# Proper way of generating dynamic javascript in Symfony 2?

Tags: javascript, symfony

I need to generate a **dynamic JSON object** using some twig function like `asset` and `translate`. I'd like to put it in an external `settings.js` file. I may use  `include 'settings.js.twig'` and put the relevant code in it.

Is this the correct way of generating dynamic javascript in Symfony 2?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you'd like to do : make a JSON object with javascript? Call a javascript in twig?

Comment: @GabrielTheron just a json object in a separate file, made up of strings that need to be translated and use some other twig functions.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but it's a similar theme. When I need to pass data from the controller/view to the javascript I usually set data attributes on the relevant HTML tags. For example, if I need a route for an AJAX request I will write

```
<a href="#updateTarget" class="ajaxTrigger" data-ajax-route="{{ path('my_ajax_route') }}">click here for ajax</a>
```

and then access it with

```
$('.ajaxTrigger').on('click', function(){
  $.getJSON($(this).data('ajax-route'), function(response) {
    // do something with response
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to call a twig in a javascript, you can make a controller that renders the twig that makes your json and call it from a javascript request (ajax or something like that).

Then you have your json in javascript and you can do whatever you need with it.

I think that doesn't completely answer your question though. I'd say you should avoid creating js with twig as much as possible.

Comment: That is a solution but it adds another request for the file, while file itself could be rendered without any need of ajax. But thanks anyway.